# Visualizing covers of $S^1\vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In looking back at my university's past topology qualifying exams, it seems that in most years there is a question of the form

> Let $X=S^1\vee S^1$. Draw a picture of the cover of $X$ corresponding to the subgroup $H=\langle\text{some generators}\rangle$ of $\pi_1(X)=\langle a,b\rangle$.

When I see a solution to this type of problem, I can see why it satisfies the right conditions, typically having to with the fact that traversing a series of loops corresponding to a generator of $H$ brings you back to the basepoint, etc. However, I'm not good at coming up with these pictures myself. Is there a general method or "trick"?

Maybe I can give some explicit examples of $H$ and people could share their "thought process" for the solution they come to. For example,

(a) take $H=\langle ab,ba\rangle$

(b) take $H=\langle(a^2b)^3,(ab)^3,bab,a^2ba^{-1}\rangle$

(c) take $H=\langle aba^{-1}b^{-1},ab^{-1}a^{-1}b,a^{-1}bab^{-1},a^{-1}b^{-1}ab\rangle$

Comment: It's gonna be hard to draw a picture for (a), since it is infinite-sheeted....

Comment: In general though, I would do this by first drawing the vertices [there will be $[G:H]$ of them].  Then, to be a covering, you just need each vertex to have two incoming edges (labeled $a$ and $b$), and two outgoing edges (also labeled $a$ and $b$). You do this in a way that the only loops at a particular vertex are the words in $H$.

Comment: Hatcher does a nice writeup on this in the opening parts of his chapter on covering spaces if I recall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a general method.

To draw the covering corresponding to $H$, you let your vertices be indexed by the cosets of $H$ in $G$; your basepoint will correspond to the coset $H$.Then you draw an $a$ edge from $C$ to $Ca$ for every coset $C$; similarly for $b$.

I can't imagine there's an easier way to handle the general case. Something helpful here is that $H$ is a free group, so it has some number $n$ of generators.  Thus your covering should be homotopic to the wedge of $n$ circles. For example, that helps me realize that the covering for (a) should look like

[image]

where each tree extends infinitely (just like the Cayley graph / universal cover for $G$).

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks

Comment: this method is actually near perfect for constructing relations. The process given here gives the [schreier grraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier_coset_graph) which is the one-skeleton of the schreier complex, which has fundamental group $$H < G$, so this will always get you the 1-skeleton of the corresponding cover. We can get the two-skeleton  by remembering the relations. See [here](https://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~nser/abstracts/subgppres.ps.gz) for some more about this.